# What to do with mundane gear in Pathfinder Society play?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-society

This might be a silly question, but the guide for PFS play doesn't specifically state (to the best of my reading) what is to be done with mundane gear that is gained.

1. Do players have an opportunity to use the items during the scenario, but "donate" them to the Society at the end of the scenario? If so, do players have to purchase items used at the end, in a similar manner as if they were to use a magical consumable like a potion or scroll?
2. Do players have the option of splitting this loot and taking it on with them to future scenarios?
3. Can players sell these items and split the gold gained?

For context, I've just started playing PFS with my home group (we're gaining experience with it before we go to PaizoCon), and none of us (including the GM) are sure what to do with items of this nature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's all the same system - you get a set amount of gold at the end of the game, which is an abstract representation of how much gold you'd have if you sold everything and split up the proceeds, plus any actual cash or rewards you might be getting. It's already got your #1 - #3 covered for you.

You can then use that gold to purchase "stuff" - whether it's loot from that game's Chronicle Sheet, loot off one of your older Chronicle Sheets, basic gear from the core books, or equipment from the [additional resources](http://paizo.com/pathfinderSociety/about/additionalResources) list (subject to the rules on that page).

One note: anything you find during a scenario can be used for free within that scenario (including single-use items), but you have to purchase it if you want it for use in *future* scenarios. You do *not* have to pay for potions and scrolls found and used during a scenario out of your gold for that scenario. (See p.19 of the Guide.)

Comment: Thanks for the last note. I've been thinking that our GM has been running that part wrong. I thought it odd that I had to pay for the potion of cure light we found and I used at the end of the scenario. It seemed kinda like punishment!